# MySQL UPDATE exhibiting weird behavior

Tags: mysql

Experiencing a weird problem with MySql database (version 5.5.11 with InnoDB engine). I am updating one particular field in in a table by executing UPDATE query from mysql prompt as follows:

```
 mysql> UPDATE table1 SET field1='new_value' WHERE id IN (5,6,7);
```

It returns a successful response with 3 rows affected.

However when I select affected rows, they still have 'old_value' for 'field1', basically UPDATE didn't change anything.

Auto-commit is set to ON on this database

```
SELECT @@autocommit;
```

returns 1.

This database is concurrently accessed by 8 application servers simultaneously. Does this problem has something to do with table locking/transaction isolation levels?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there any trigger on table?

Comment: No, this table doesn't have any triggers.

Comment: Just because `@@autocommit=1` does not mean that your `UPDATE` was not performed in a transaction that is still awaiting a commit...